# Connection string error in C# Windows Form app

Tags: c#, sql, error-handling

I am new in C# and I am currently learning windows form. I am getting an error regarding the connection string while connecting to local database. The error I'm getting is Sql is in the following line -

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="c: \users\devesh lashkari\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DemoApp1.0\DemoApp1.0\DemoAppDataBase.mdf";Integrated Security=True");
    }
```

Here, I am getting error in the file name. I have attached a Screenshot so that it will be easy to detect.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to escape the quotation marks? It looks like you have one quoted string for your data source, which stops when you start to attach a filename. (I'm not sure this is your issue, but the syntax highlighting does seem to hint this may be an issue.) Edit: see @MickyD 's answer below

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of choices:

### Escape everything

Try this instead:

```
    con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;" +
                            "AttachDbFilename=\"c:\\users\\devesh lashkari\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\DemoApp1.0\DemoApp1.0\\DemoAppDataBase.mdf\";" +
                            "Integrated Security=True");
```

### Double Quote

...or if you want to use the `@` you need to use double quotes as mentioned by [GalacticCowboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29638/galacticcowboy) (below):

```
    con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=""c:\users\devesh lashkari\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DemoApp1.0\DemoApp1.0\DemoAppDataBase.mdf"";Integrated Security=True");
```

Note, it's not so much a SQL error rather a c# *escaping error*.  You need the quote in the path so you can't use `@`.  I've broken it up into multiple lines to make it easier to read.

Also you had a space after the `c:`

Thanks to [GalacticCowboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29638/galacticcowboy) for the tip and for spotting my silliness. ;)

Comment: If you want a string literal (`@`) and embedded quotes, double them up. As so: `@"This string has ""embedded"" quotes."` Also note that your version won't work because the backslashes need to be escaped, whereas it would work with a string literal.